# Angular-Charts, Map char-Labels to Property of object Array

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-chart

I'm using angularJs Charts 
http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

I have an array of objects like:
var MyArray = [{a: 1, b: 2,c:3}, {a: 3, b: 4,c:10}, {a: 5, b: 6,c:20}, {a: 7, b: 8,c:30}];

I want to bind chart-labels to the property a,
  and chart-data to the property b.a

Answer (score 0):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
scope.labels = MyArray.map(x => x.a);
scope.data = MyArray.map(x => x.b);
```